# Trying to call a function and returning the data in a post method

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, puppeteer, aws-sdk-nodejs

I am new to Nodejs, so finding difficult to achieve the above-mentioned task. Trying to call an async function and return its value in response for a POST method

```js
    module.exports.pdf = async(event, context, callBack) => {

    const data = {
         title: " Pdf generation using puppeteer",
         text: " Handlebar is awesome!"
    }
    const executablePath = event.isOffline ?
         "./node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/mac-674921/chrome-mac/Chromium.app/Contents/MacOS/Chromium" :
         await chromium.executablePath;
    const file = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, "template.hbs"), 'utf8')
    const template = handlebars.compile(file)
    const html = template(data)

    let browser = null;

    try {
         browser = await chromium.puppeteer.launch({
              args: chromium.args,
              defaultViewport: chromium.defaultViewport,
              executablePath,
              headless: chromium.headless
         });

         const page = await browser.newPage();

         page.setContent(html);

         const pdf = await page.screenshot({ encoding: "base64" })

         // const pdf = await page.pdf({
         //      format: "A4",
         //      printBackground: true,
         //      margin: { top: "1cm", right: "1cm", bottom: "1cm", left: "1cm" }
         // });

         // TODO: Response with PDF (or error if something went wrong )
         const response = {
              headers: {
                   "Content-type": "application/json",
                   "content-disposition": "attachment; filename=test.pdf"
              },
              statusCode: 200,
              body: pdf.toString("base64"),
              isBase64Encoded: true
         };

         const output_filename = 'pdf-demo.json';

         const s3Params = {
              Bucket: "pdf-demo-screenshot",
              Key: `public/pdfs/${output_filename}`,
              Body: pdf,
              ContentType: "application/json",
              ServerSideEncryption: "AES256"
         };

         s3.putObject(s3Params, err => {
              if (err) {
                   console.log("err", err);
                   return callBack(null, { error });
              }
         });

         context.succeed(response);

    } catch (error) {
         return context.fail(error);
    } finally {
         if (browser !== null) {
              await browser.close();
         }
    }
};
```

I have the above function. I have a global variable `let img_arr = []`. And the below POST method where I want to call the above function and push the base64 data into the array and return the array in the response.

```
app.use('/screenshot', function(req, res) {
 res.send(img_arr)})
```

Comment: [ https://codissimo.sinumo.tech/2019/12/27/serverless-puppeteer-with-aws-lambda-layers-and-node-js/ ] Best example found on the web for using puppeteer on lambda(Serverless)